# Constraint for specific domain and generic subdomains in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, subdomain

in my routes I have a constraint for subdomain "members" like this :

```
constraints subdomain: "members" do

    get '/somethig', to: 'controller_1#show'

end
```

I would like to get any other subdomain than "members" to another controller, so I added another constraint like this :

```
constraints subdomain: /.+/ do

      get '', to: 'controller_2#show'

  end
```

now all subdomains including "members" are redirected to controller_2#show

How I can solve that

Comment: You're not specifying a path in the second route.  What path are you using to test?  Also, Rails checks for route matches in the order they are declared, so the members route should come first.  Maybe you can post your full routes file and the Rails logs of your tests.

Comment: BillDoughty yes members route is first and the generic constraint is second, I am not specifying the path because I want any other subdomain than "members" with any path to go to controller_2, it doesn't matter what the path is